# Excel Macro for copy and paste according to comboBox item

Tags: excel, vba

I have a comboboxin excel, based on the item selected in it i want to copy data from one sheet to another. Below is a part of the code when I run it i get "Run time error 1004 " I am a started in VBA

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

     Dim firstLimit As Integer
     Dim secondLimit As Integer
     firstLimit = 2
     secondLimit = 2

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Worksheets("output").Range("A2:U2").Value =   Worksheets("Input").Range(Cells(firstLimit, "A"), Cells(secondLimit, "U")).Value
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True


     End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the unqualified calls to `Cells`.  In your code these will refer to the active sheet.  If this is not "Input", then an error occurs.

Change to

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim firstLimit As Integer
    Dim secondLimit As Integer
    firstLimit = 2
    secondLimit = 2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Input")
        Worksheets("output").Range("A2:U2").Value = .Range(.Cells(firstLimit, "A"), .Cells(secondLimit, "U")).Value
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Note the`.`'s before `Range` and the two `Cells`